# Use HTTPS to connect to MarkLogic host from ml-gradle

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, ml-gradle

How do I force ml-gradle to use HTTPS instead of HTTP to connect to a MarkLogic host?

I have something like following in my gradle.properties file:

```
mlHost=abc.xyz.aws.private
```

mlDeploy task calls the host using HTTP like this:

```
http://abc.xyz.aws.private
```

How can I force it to use HTTPS like this:

```
https://abc.xyz.aws.private
```

Note that following doesn't work:

```
mlHost=https://abc.xyz.aws.private
```

My MarkLogic host is on AWS. Version 10.0-9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/SSL-with-Manage-and-Admin-servers

> In version 3.0.0, you can setup a simple SSL context while connecting to the Manage and/or Admin app servers by setting the appropriate properties:

```
mlManageSimpleSsl=true
mlManageScheme=https
mlAdminSimpleSsl=true
mlAdminScheme=https
```