Marklogic ml-gradle: 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
We've recently migrated to https with our self-hosted MarkLogic instance and struggle to deploy roles to it using ml-gradle. Other resources deploy just fine, but mlDeployRoles seems to ignore https settings.
I've been searching through all available resources but found no information on mlDeployRoles using other custom attributes.
I tried:
mlManageScheme=https
mlAdminSimpleSsl=true
mlAdminScheme=https
mlAppServicesSimpleSsl=true

from:
https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.7/refs/data-hub-properties.html
Then I tried:
hubSsl=true

all of them seem to ignore mlDeployRoles and give error:
2024-08-29 05:39:08Z - Error - Step: mlDeployRoles. Error with message: Error occurred while sending POST request to /manage/v3; logging request body to assist with debugging: {} Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: <html> <head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head> <body> <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center> <center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center> </body> </html> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':mlDeployRoles'.
> 400 Bad Request: "<html><EOL><EOL><head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head><EOL><EOL><body><EOL><EOL><center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center><EOL><EOL><center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center><EOL><EOL></body><EOL><EOL></html><EOL><EOL>"

I was searching through https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/blob/8b516c6f35a91e28f3af9cff83f8eddaa2c1534e/src/main/groovy/com/marklogic/gradle/MarkLogicPlugin.groovy#L303 but can't find any clues on how this differs from for example mlDeployDatabase task.
I'm using:

id "com.marklogic.ml-gradle" version "4.5.3"
mlcp "com.marklogic:mlcp:11.1.0"
MarkLogic Server Essential Enterprise 10.0-11
gradle-7.3.3
openjdk-17-jdk


There are many changes between versions of ml-gradle and also ml-app-deployer over the years and across versions of MarkLogic.
Please help by providing additional information:

version of ml-gradle
version of MarkLogic
version of DHF, if used


@DavidEnnis-CleverLlamas.com updated with all the versions of tools I'm using to deploy. Sorry for missing that :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73869997/14419

@MadsHansen sorry, I have pasted wrong properties I'm setting. I'm using exactly the same as you pasted. It does not affect mlDeployRoles

Can you create a ticket at https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/issues for this? Include the output when including "--stacktrace". There's definitely nothing different about deploying roles, every command is using the same connection to the Manage server on 8002.

@rjrudin --debug helped me narrowing down the issue. It was gradle.properties with ssl enabled being in wrong directory. Thank you all!
